# progressBar setVisibility VISIBLE

Tags: java, android

I am new at JAVA so i'm trying to show progressbar visible when programmers list will render but progressBar is visible all the time

public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Repository repository;

```
private final List<Programmer> programmers = new ArrayList<>();

private ListView listView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;


private ProgrammersListAdapter programmersListAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    repository = CombinedRepository.getInstance();

    // It's important not to change reference of the list provided here. That's why it's final!
    programmersListAdapter = new ProgrammersListAdapter(this, programmers);
    listView.setAdapter(programmersListAdapter);
    refreshProgrammers();
}

void refreshProgrammers(){
    // ToDO: Change Progress bar visibility here
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    this.programmers.clear();

    // Without notifyDataSetChanged - Listview won't know that there's been update to it's data
    this.programmersListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    repository.getProgrammers(programmers -> {
        this.programmers.clear();
        this.programmers.addAll(programmers);
        this.programmersListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` from `onCreate` and do the hiding in the callback to `getProgrammers`:

```
repository.getProgrammers(programmers -> {
    this.programmers.clear();
    this.programmers.addAll(programmers);
    this.programmersListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hide progressBar after data is loaded
});
```

I also suggest to use [`View.GONE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#GONE) instead of [`View.INVISIBLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#INVISIBLE) so the progressBar won't take up any space when invisible.